# Root system as a category

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras, functors

I'm studying Lie Algebras from Humphreys's book. The definition of isomorphism of root systems seems to me to have some functor properties:
if $\phi:(\Phi,E)\to(\Phi', E')$ is an isomorphism of euclidean spaces $E,E'$ and root systems $\Phi,\Phi'$, then for any root $\alpha\in\Phi$ we have $\sigma_{\phi(\alpha)}\circ \phi=\phi\circ\sigma_{\alpha}$.

My question is:
Is there any way to see a root system as a category and an isomorphism between root systems as functor between categories? The idea is the same to think about a group (or a monoid, or a POSET, ecc) as a unique category.

For example, if we see the Weyl's groups as categories, $\phi$ defines a functor between them.

My idea is to use the reflections $\sigma_{\alpha}$ as morphisms and the roots as objects, but I think something is missing.

Comment: I don't know anything about this topic, but I'll mention that there's [a category of root systems](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/the-category-of-root-systems/) and an isomorphism in that category is an isomorphism of root systems (as usually defined).

Comment: Thank you @S.C., I saw that already, but my question is different. As one can see monoids, groups, POSETs, etc, as a category, I'd like to see a root system as a category.

Comment: What are the functor-like properties you have in mind?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov I made and edit to the post.

Comment: If you take roots as objects (which on first sight seems plausible), then a morphism between two roots $\alpha, \beta$ should be something that depends on both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which makes $\sigma_\alpha$ not plausible. Maybe something like the Cartan coefficient $n(\alpha, \beta)$ would be a good candidate? (The scalar product $(\alpha, \beta)$ feels too symmetric to give something interesting.) But then the obvious next question is, what would composition of such morphisms be?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg what if we define $\hom (\alpha,\beta)$ to be the set of reflections in the Weyl's group taking $\alpha$ to $\beta$? In this case we have the identities, it Is empty in some cases and it has two elements in others...

Comment: If by refelection you really mean only elements of the form $s_\alpha$, then I do not think we have identities in general (already not in type $A_1$; as you say yourself, that set might be empty), and I also do not see your claim about two elements, or how composition would work ...? One can of course take just all elements of the Weyl group which take $\alpha$ to $\beta$; I think then all axioms of a category are satisfied. The question is what insight we gained. Do these categories all have a certain property p, and could we recover a unique root system from each category with property p?